# sqlyog not updating records

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I tried updating records from sqlyog but they were not updated.

i tried running this sql query but still got result 0 rows affected. 
UPDATE `website_prod` SET `website_name`='Papers',`prod_name`='Regular',`days`='10',`price`='9.99' WHERE `website_name`='Papers' AND `prod_name`='Regular' AND `days`='5' AND `price`='9.99';

Can anyone explain why the record is not getting updated even thou i am changing values of days from 10 to 5.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there are no records for which all those conditions are true. Also, you're updating fields that already have the value you are assigning to them (because of the conditions)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [this](http://webyog.com/faq/content/29/162/en/tables-with-floating-point-datatypes-fail-to-update.html) problem?

(it is same problem with UPDATE and DELETE)

If you have FLOATING POINT data types you should always have a Primary key on the table based on non-floating columns.